# How the current actually flows in a circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, conductors, batteries

I'm studying about electricity and i'm quite lost.

Given the circuit in the picture, I just want to know how the current flows through the points A, B, C, D.

The condition to have current between 2 points is to have potential difference between them.

From what I understand, between A and D, there is a potential difference of 220V. Between B and C, there is also a potential difference of 220V. Therefore, there is a current from A to D (and from B to C).

Suppose that the wire has no resistence, then I understand that A and B are at the same potential (so no potential difference), and so are C and D. Therefore, there is no current between A/B and C/D. But how can it be correct while there is a current from A to D which envelops everything ?

Could you please tell me the right way of thinking ? Thank you very much for your help!
[image]

Comment: Sometimes it helps to look at this from a different perspective. The water-electricity analogy provides a visual aid: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/watcir.html

Comment: Am I imagining it, or did you just make a comment on my answer and then delete it?

Comment: @BobD: Hello, yes, because i posted it in the wrong thread. The true thread is the one with your beautiful schema.

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge Just out of curiosity, are you a student? If yes, what level and where?

Comment: No i'm not a student, i'm working. i have a bachelor in economics but electronics always impresses me. I know Ohm's law (the basics) but there are some fundamental questions that I can't understand, like you said potential difference isn't necessary to have current, but there isn't any current flow from hot wire to ground (through the neutral wire), and people say it is because there is no potential difference between ground and neutral wire. that confuses me and I'm trying to understand the coherence here.

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge I understand. I’ve added a new paragraph to my answer. Maybe it will help

Answer (score 5):

> The condition to have current between 2 points is to have potential
> difference between them.

No.

The potential difference between two points is defined as the work required per unit charge to move the charge between the points. If the resistance between two points is theoretically zero, no electrical work per unit charge (potential difference) is needed to move the charge between the the points.

A mechanical analog is an object (analogous to charge) moving between two points at constant speed (analogous to current), on a friction free surface (analogous to zero electrical resistance), without requiring any mechanical work per unit mass (analogous to electrical work per unit charge- i.e. voltage).

However, just like all surfaces have some friction, all conductors, with the exception of superconductors, have some resistance. Generally, however, the resistance of wires connected between circuit components is considered so low compared to the components they connect, we assign the wires zero resistance.

> From what I understand, between A and D, there is a potential
> difference of 220V. Between B and C, there is also a potential
> difference of 220V. Therefore, there is a current from A to D (and
> from B to C).

The potential difference between points B and C will be 220 V if all the wires have zero resistance. If the wires have resistance, there will be voltage drops in the wires.

> Suppose that the wire has no resistence, then I understand that A and
> B are at the same potential (so no potential difference), and so are C
> and D.

Correct. And now you can say that the potential difference between A and D is the same as between B and C.

> Therefore, there is no current between A/B and C/D.

No. As I stated initially you theoretically don't need resistance between two points to have current flow. It is analogous to an object moving at constant speed on a frictionless surface without the need for work.

It might help if you thought about “potential difference” as follows: There is the potential difference that ***produces*** current in a circuit. That’s the potential difference between the battery terminals (energy source) of your circuit. Then there’s the potential differences ***produced by*** the current flowing through resistance in the circuit. Those are the potential differences between A and B, between B and C, and between C and D in the circuit.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

A and B are at the same potential so $\Delta V = V_A - V_B = 0$.

The resistance of AB section is R = 0 as you stated.

Writing the normal $V = I R$ relationship as $$I = \frac{\Delta V}{R}$$ the result is $$I = \frac{0}{0} $$ which is not zero but indeterminate. That means we have to find it another way.

One way we can do that is to note that instead of using the potential drop from B to C we can use the potential drop from A to C to calculate the current and we get the same result either way because the potential difference is the same. The current that flow through the resistor must be the same as the current that flows through the wire before it as there are no junctions.

[Kirchoff's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#:%7E:text=This%20law%2C%20also%20called%20Kirchhoff%27s%20first%20law%2C%20or,of%20conductors%20meeting%20at%20a%20point%20is%20zero.) states that if we pick any point in a circuit (e.g point B) then the total current flowing into that point is equal to the total current flowing out of that point. Usually the point under consideration is a junction with more than two wires, but in this case the law still applies and the current flow flowing from A to B must be the same as the current flow from B to C.

You can think of it this way. When a current flows around a circuit it consists of a number (N) of electrons leaving the battery and N electrons returning to the battery. The number of electrons flowing in a section remains the same everywhere except where the circuit divides like where we have two resistors in parallel, but when the the two flows rejoin after the parallel resistors, the number of electrons per unit time (current) is the same before and after the parallel resistors.

Yet another way to think of it is this. Imagine  we have a stream flowing down from a mountain into a lake. At the other end of the lake is a dam and to keep the level of the lake constant any water that enters the lake must flow over the top of the dam. The flow of the stream is proportional to the difference in height or potential. The difference in height of the water at one end of the dam compared to the other is imperceptible, yet the amount of water per unit time flowing through the lake and exiting the other end is exactly the same as the flow in the stream feeding the lake. It is a bit like putting water into a hose. Whatever enters at one end must exit at the other end, if there are no junctions splitting off from the hose.

In practice, unless the wire between A and B is a super conductor, the resistance is not exactly zero and there is a tiny perhaps difficult to measure resistance. There is also a tiny potential difference across the wire that is also difficult to measure, like it would be difficult to measure the difference in height between one end of the lake compared to the other. Let's say the resistor BC is 2 Ohms. The current in the circuit would then be $\frac{V}{R} = \frac{220}{2} = 110$ Amps. Now lets say the real resistance of the wire between A and B is $0.0000000000000001$ Ohms. The voltage drop across the wire would be $V_{AB} = I R = 110 * 0.0000000000000001 = 0.000000000000011$ Volts which would be difficult to detect.

Answer (score 1):

the positive terminal of the battery keeps gulping on the electrons from the wire while the negative terminalkeeps supplying the electrons to the wire. the wire is electrically neutral.